# add checkbox with simple_form without association with model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

How I can add checkbox with simple_form without association with model?
I want to create checkbox which will handle some javascript events, but don't know?
Maybe I miss something in documentation?
Want't to use similar like following:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_url(resource_name), wrapper: :inline) do |f|
  .inputs
    = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true
    = f.input :password, required: false
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
    = my_checkbox, 'some text'
```

Comment: if this checkbox haven't association with model why dont use standart checkbox helper? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

Comment: I dont think you can use simple_form helpers without record field. Jus t use simple_form generated classes for your checkbox and you dont need to add custom css. Im notice that you are from Sevastopol come in to our local Sevastopol.rb meetup in this Thusday! Cheers!

Comment: Thank's, I looking about all changes in that group. But weather not corresponding to nice walking, maybe in Marth)

Answer (score 36):

You can add a custom attribute to the model:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :custom_field
end
```

Then use this field as block:

```
= f.input :custom_field, :label => false do 
  = check_box_tag :some_name
```

Try to find "Wrapping Rails Form Helpers" in their documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 35):

You could use

```
f.input :field_name, as: :boolean
```

Comment: please notice `without association with model`

if the `field_name` is not defined in the model it wont work

Answer (score 18):

The command proposed by huoxito does not work (at least not in Rails 4). As far as I figured out the error is caused by Rails trying to look up the default value for `:custom_field`, but because this field does not exists this lookup fails and an exception is thrown.

However, it works if you specify a default value for the field using the `:input_html` parameter, e.g. like this:

```
= f.input :custom_field, :as => :boolean, :input_html => { :checked => "checked" }
```

Answer (score 3):

This question comes first on google with no appropriate answer.

Since Simple Form 3.1.0.rc1 there is a proper way of doing it explained on the wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes

> `app/inputs/fake_input.rb`:

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  # This method only create a basic input without reading any value from object
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, nil, merged_input_options)
  end
end
```

> Then you can do `<%= f.input :thing, as: :fake %>`

For this specific question you have to change the second line of the method to:

```
template.check_box_tag(attribute_name, nil, merged_input_options)
```

For versions prior 3.1.0.rc1 admgc gave a solution that is adding the missing method `merge_wrapper_options`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331237/2055246

Answer (score 3):

Add this to `app/inputs/arbitrary_boolean_input.rb`:

```
class ArbitraryBooleanInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    tag_name = "#{@builder.object_name}[#{attribute_name}]"
    template.check_box_tag(tag_name, options['value'] || 1, options['checked'], options)
  end
end
```

then use it in your views like:

```
= simple_form_for(@some_object, remote: true, method: :put) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for @some_object.some_nested_object do |nested_f|
    = nested_f.input :some_param, as: :arbitrary_boolean
```

i.e. The above implementation supports nested fields correctly. Other solutions I've seen do not.

***Note:*** This example is HAML.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation:

```
= f.label :some_param, class: "label__class" do
  = f.input_field :some_param, class: "checkbox__class"
  Label text
```