# Adding checkbox to simple form for input not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm trying to add a checkbox input to my simple form in Rails. I only need the input for javascript and don't actually want it in my model file.

I've learned that in order to add inputs to simple form that do not exist in the model a value has to be passed in the parameters

```
input_html: {value: true}
```

This works for a text input, but I can't get it working for a checkbox.

I've tried

```
<%= f.input :current_job, :as => :check_box, input_html: {value: false} %>
```

and

```
<%= f.input :current_job, :as => :check_box, input_html: {checked: false} %>
```

But I get an error saying

```
No input found for check_box
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [add checkbox with simple\_form without association with model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182434/add-checkbox-with-simple-form-without-association-with-model)

Answer (score 15):

You should use type as **boolean** in your fields. In your case, you can change this:

```
 <%= f.input :current_job, :as => :check_box, input_html: {checked: false} %>
```

to this:

```
 <%= f.input :current_job, :as => :boolean, input_html: {checked: false} %>
```